# Inserindo dados em banco de dados postgresSQL com PHO, AJAX e JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estou tentando inserir dados em um banco de dados postgres utilizando php e ajax com jquery. Porém sempre da erro. É para um trabalho de faculdade. Alguém poderia me explicar o erro no código?

```js
$("#registrar").click(function(){
        $.ajax ({
            url : "registra.php",
            method: "POST",
            dataType : "json",
            data : {participante1 : $("#participante1 option:selected").val(),
                    participante2 : $("#participante2 option:selected").val(),
                    score1 : $("#score1").val(),
                    score2 : $("#score2").val()},

            success : function(resp){
                alert("Registro efetuado com sucesso!");
            },

            error : function(err){
                alert("ERRO: " + err.status);
            }
        });
    });
```

```
<?php 
    $con = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=Jogos user=postgres password=postgres");
    $participante1 = $_POST['participante1'];
    $participante2 = $_POST['participante2'];
    $score1 = $_POST['score1'];
    $score2 = $_POST['score2'];
    $comando = "INSERT INTO disputas (participante1, participante2, score1, score2) VALUES ('$participante1', '$participante2', '$score1', '$score2')"
    pg_query($con, $comando);
    pg_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Qual é o erro que dá?

Comment: Faça assim e veja qual erro aparece. `pg_query($con, $comando); or die(pg_last_error($con));`

Comment: Aparece o mesmo erro. "ERRO : 200"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valeu pela ajuda pessoa, estava faltando o bendito ";" no final desse trecho

```
$comando = "INSERT INTO disputas (participante1, participante2, score1, score2) VALUES ('$participante1', '$participante2', '$score1', '$score2')"
```

Quanto ao erro 200 que estava apresentando, é porque o PHP não estava retornando um JSON válido.

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

`INSERT INTO disputas (participante1, participante2, score1, score2) VALUES (".$participante1.", ".$participante2.", ".$score1.", ".$score2.")`

Comment: Também não funciona.

Comment: Instale um Pgadmin na sua maquina conecte com o banco o rode essa query no console trocando as variaveis pelo valores reais e veja se o erro se repete!